# Whats is the difference between CachingConnectionFactory and ConnectionFactory?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Here is the javadocs for CachingConnectionFactory,
I cannot quite understand what they exactly mean, is there any simpler explaination?

link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html

Comment: A ConnectionFactory `IMPLEMENTATION` that (when the cache mode is CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CHANNEL (default) returns the same Connection from all createConnection() calls, and ignores calls to Connection.close() and caches Channel.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `ConnectionFactory` `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` (which is a concrete class) and `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory`.

Spring connection factory implementations (there are several) wrap the com.rabbitmq one to add additional functionality (like caching connections and channels).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#choosing-factory